# GE Dishwasher - three beeps, no start

Tags: repair, appliances, dishwasher

My GE Dishwasher (GDF520PGJ2CC) beeps three times and doesn't start upon pressing Start. According to my research, this indicates that the washer thinks that the door is open and that the culprit is either the locking piece or the control board.

This first happened after a power outage. The fix was to turn the breaker off and back on a few minutes later. Since then, this has happened a few more times and it seems that every time, it required us to turn the breaker off for a longer period of time. Until about a week ago, when turning the breaker off and on doesn't help at all.

Given this history, is it more likely to be the locking mechanism or the control board? Or perhaps a bad contact somewhere between the lock and the control board?

Comment: all of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is likely on the control board. My SILs washer has the same exact issue. The troubleshooting mode says it is the door switch but it shows contact when I test it. I may get both parts and return the one not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't going to be a simple, pat answer to this question. You're going to have to do some investigation, probably using a multi-meter as a continuity tester. The good news, though, is that you no longer have an intermittent issue to track down, but a steady failure. Those are much easier to find.

Get the wiring diagram for your dishwasher and start tracing the wiring to determine where you're not getting a connection. That will be the culprit. You may have to replace a wire, a connection, a switch or the control board. You may end up having to replace more than one component. Fortunately, wires and connectors are cheap. Switches shouldn't be too bad. If it gets to the control board, that's where prices start going up and you may want to think about the value proposition of replacing electronics vs replacing the whole dishwasher.